# Is there any Treebank for free?

Tags: nlp, dataset, tagging, corpus

Is any place I can download Treebank of English phrases for free or less than $100? I need training data containing bunch of syntactic parsed sentences (>1000) in English in any format. Basically all I need is just words in this sentences being recognized by part of speech.

Comment: Does NLTK not contain a sizeable subset of the Penn Treebank?

Comment: @on-hold: actually, this is a very useful question and the answers are also very useful, since these are comparatively scarce resources. Mind, this is not a "is A better then B" question, but a "list all resources of type X under condition Y".

Comment: It's ridiculous that the LDC charges for data sets... Anyway, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treebank#Syntactic_treebanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) (for Python) offers several [treebanks for free](http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/).

Comment: Thanks, +1. I'm not familiar with Python, so advise me please how can I parse this *.pickle files? Is any converter to something more user friendly like XML or just plain text?

Comment: What pickle file? The Treebanks are in text format. E.g., http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nltk_data/packages/corpora/treebank.zip .

Comment: 19 languages for free here: http://universaldependencies.github.io/docs/

Comment: Hindi and Urdu Dependency treebank: http://ltrc.iiit.ac.in/treebank_H2014/

Answer (score 24):

Here are a couple (English) treebanks available for free:

- American National Corpus: [MASC](http://www.anc.org/data/masc/downloads/data-download/)
- Questions: [QuestionBank](http://www.computing.dcu.ie/~jjudge/qtreebank/) and [Stanford's corrections](http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/QuestionBank-Stanford.shtml)
- British news: [BNC](http://nclt.computing.dcu.ie/~jfoster/resources/bnc1000.html)
- TED talks: [NAIST-NTT TED Treebank](http://ahclab.naist.jp/resource/tedtreebank/)
- Georgetown University Multilayer Corpus: [GUM](http://corpling.uis.georgetown.edu/gum/)
- Biomedical:

  - [NaCTeM GENIA treebank](http://www.nactem.ac.uk/genia/genia-corpus/treebank)
  - [Brown GENIA treebank](http://bllip.cs.brown.edu/resources.shtml)
  - [CRAFT corpus](http://bionlp-corpora.sourceforge.net/CRAFT/)

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treebank#Syntactic_treebanks) for a huge list.

Answer (score -1):

what about Penn Treebank? I hope it will be free or atleast afordable.
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/cdrom2.html

Comment: It costs $3150 at LDC: http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/CatalogEntry.jsp?catalogId=LDC99T42

Comment: It's included, along with lots of other treebanks, in OntoNotes 4.0 http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/catalogEntry.jsp?catalogId=LDC2011T03 which is free (though you have to pay a distribution cost).

Comment: how do you the distribution cost??

Comment: @CpILL You need to register to the website. It's a shame that some NLP researchers don't share data sets for free. LDC data sets can be really expensive. To make it worse, the taxpayers fund that nonsense.

Comment: @JeffKaufman It's ridiculous it cannot be downloaded. 30 USD for shipping one DVD…