# Editing the NLTK Corpus

Tags: python, nltk, corpus, tagged-corpus

In addition to the corpus that comes with nltk I want to train it with my own corpus that follows the same part of speech rules. How can I find the corpus that it is using, and how can I add my own corpus (in addition, not as a replacement)?

**EDIT:** Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
inpy = raw_input("$")
text = nltk.word_tokenize(inpy)
d = nltk.pos_tag(text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLTK comes with a substantial number of different corpora. It would help if you specified in more detail which corpus you want to augment. The main English POS corpus in NLTK is the [Brown corpus](http://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html#tagged-corpora). See also http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html as well as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Corpus and http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/

Comment: I am using the UPenn tagset (I believe. I am not 100% sure). I don't want to augment them but add a corpus so that when it trains its classifier, it can be more accurate.

Comment: Then it's probably the fragment from the Penn Treebank; #17 from the last link. You might then actually be better off replacing it entirely because it's rather old and gritty; google for English treebank corpora.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949517/is-there-any-treebank-for-free and https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2012T13 out of the top Google results.